# Laravel - Mail fails when email address is in variable, works when hardcoded

Tags: php, email, laravel, smtp, sendmail

Im using Laravel class Mail to send emails to customer:

```
$item = DB::table('questions')->find($id);

var_dump($item->email);

// send mail to customer
Mail::queue('emails.email', $data, function($message) {     

    $message->to($item->email)->subject('Odpoveď od SCSPPIMKA');    
    $message->sender('mailer@scspimka.sk');

});
```

When I hardcode email address in `$message->to('example@email.com')` everything works fine, but when I use email address in variable: `$message->to($item->email)` I get error:

```
Undefined variable: item' in /data/www/scsppimka.local/laravel/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(99) : eval()'d code:2
```

Vardump of $item->email shows string with correct e-mail address. What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need use `use` to take `$item` variable from current context to the context of the anonymous function:

```
Mail::queue('emails.email', $data, function($message) use ($item) {     

    $message->to($item->email)->subject('Odpoveď od SCSPPIMKA');    
    $message->sender('mailer@scspimka.sk');

});
```

Comment: How can I pass multiple variable in use() ??